# Can I use "It helps having a good imagination" instead of "It helps to have..."?

Tags: sentence-construction

In this sentence, can I also say "It helps **having** a good imagination"?

> It helps **to have** a good imagination, and I am completely delusional.
>   —— Hoult (A movie director)

Which usage would be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say that provided the listener/reader knows the context you are talking about. However, the [COCAE](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) shows that *'helps to have'* is more frequently used as compared to *'helps having'*.

We should carefully use the verbs as they have particular *verb pattern* that decides whether a verb would be followed by a gerund or an infinitive. The given link (of a post and not COCAE here) gives better idea to use them.

The sentence with the verb *help* and an object.

The above sentence does not have *object* or else it could have been the *verb help* [followed by an object before the infinitive verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329/when-should-a-verb-be-followed-by-a-gerund-instead-of-an-infinitive). In addition, the verb *help* is also a causative verb and thus can also be followed by a simple form (no *to* or *-ing*)

> It helps **me** have a good imagination OR 
>   It helps **me** to have a good imagination.

Additional info: If it's [*can't help*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329/when-should-a-verb-be-followed-by-a-gerund-instead-of-an-infinitive), it takes the gerund (-ing).

Comment: My understanding is that the sentence could be transformed into "To have a good imagination helps." If so, then "having" as a gerund also seems fine to the sentence, since it would be "Having a good imagination helps." Is that so?

Comment: @dennylv *It helps to have... something* and *To have something...helps* are two different contexts. The previous one says that there is something that helps you to have imagination* whereas the latter one indicates that *you already have good imagination and that helps you to do something*. That's why I wrote, *provided the reader knows what you are talking about.

Comment: Very clear explanation, I got it.

Comment: Plus, do you mean that "It helps have a good imagination" is also a correct sentence?

Comment: @dennylv Without any previous explanation, I won't prefer that without an object! Better put some object to use it correctly. *It helps me/you/us...*

Comment: @DamkerngT. Ture. I told there that in that context, to make it clear, the OP *may* add an object.

Comment: I can see it in a comment now. However, I think *It helps me ...*, though useful (and it is a great ELU answer), is not very relevant to the question. dennylv's first comment under this answer was already right. And I'm not sure how specific context we need to have (according to "the listener/reader knows the context you are talking about"). (In a way, I think we can say we can't write anything out of context.) For example, I think I can say "It helps to have someone to talk to" without any specific context.

Comment: @DamkerngT. My answer was over on very second sentence! But then I thought to give additional information that would help the OP to how to use the verb *help* in other context. *provided...* was added since that sentence does not have object and I was to explain something about the verb with an object in a sentence.